# jQuery - .removeClass doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button `<button id="subs1">test</button>` and a div

```
<div class="subsystem subhide">
  <h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; font-weight: normal;">Electronics</h3>
  <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
```

In the css file the class .subhide is defined as

```
.subhide {
 display: none;
}
```

and the jQuery code that I'm trying to get to work is

```
jQuery('#subs1').on('click', function(){
jQuery('.subsystem').removeClass('subhide');
});
```

When clicking the button nothing happens, why is that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you check for errors also create a demo?

Comment: What is the role of subsystem? Add subsystem CSS please

Comment: Did you include the jquery library?

Comment: working https://jsfiddle.net/78k8dkq5/

Comment: Whats your jquery version? .on was introduced since 1.7

Comment: @AlexeyShchur Console gives out 2.1.1, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: @Skydiver very intriguing. It would be really helpful if you publish your code somewhere so people can look at it and help you

Comment: @AlexeyShchur I found a working solution (see below), although I'm not really sure why it works. Maybe you can figure out the difference between this and the initial snippet.

Comment: @Skydiver, well you're changing several things there 1) wrapping by "on document ready" 2) using ".find(selector)" vs jQuery(selector) 3) using actually addClass vs removeClass :) Try disabling each of the things one by one, and you then eventually figure out what exactly was the non-working thing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `jQuery('#subs1')` finds elements with that id and binds to them. If elements don't have the id at the time the binding is made, the events will not be handled.

## Attach on DOM ready

To solve this issue, wrap the code with `on document ready`, this way your code will execute only when your dom (document) is ready.

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

## A better approach

On the other hand, if your button is dynamically added, it will not be there when the event listener wants to be binded, so the code will practically do nothing. To solve this issue, change your code to the following:

```
jQuery(document.body).on('click', '#subs1', function() {
    jQuery('.subsystem').removeClass('subhide');
});
```

This event will be attached to the `document.body` which is always there in the DOM tree. Now when the body is clicked, the event will propagate to `#subs1` regardless of the time the button was attached to the DOM.

## Working Snippet

Here is a working example:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery(document.body).on('click', '#subs1', function() {
    jQuery('.subsystem').removeClass('subhide');
  });

  jQuery(document.body).on('click', '#subs2', function() {
    jQuery('.subsystem').addClass('subhide');
  });
});
```

```css
.subhide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="subs1">Unhide</button>
<button id="subs2">hide</button>
<div class="subsystem subhide">
  <h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; font-weight: normal;">Electronics</h3>
  <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. If I copy your code into jsfiddle it works, but it doesn't on my website. I know that jQuery works as there are some other functions that use it which work. Guess I'm all out of luck on this one.

Comment: @Skydiver if you can link a snippet maybe i can help out more. (on a gist or something). is the button on the screen from the first load? or is it dynamically added?

Comment: Well there really is nothing more to it, the js code is below the working js code, the css code is below the working css code and the div is befor the closing </body> tag. No other wraps or additional features.

Comment: @Skydiver try my updated answer, im sure it will solve you issue.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. I really am all out of ideas, it must be something fundamental that is not related to the code I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#subs1').on('click', function(){
          $('body').find('.subhide').removeClass('subhide');
      });
   });
```

and if you use chrome, clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery('#subs1').on('click', function(){
jQuery('.subsystem').removeClass('subhide');
});


jQuery('#toggle').on('click', function(){
jQuery('.subsystem').toggle('subhide');
});
```

```css
.subhide {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subsystem subhide">
  <h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; font-weight: normal;">Electronics</h3>
  <p>Lorem</p>
</div> 
<button id="subs1">Button</button>

<button id="toggle">Toggle Button</button>
```

You need to define button outside of class

**Hope this help!**

Answer (score 1):

In the stylesheet, change it to:

`.subsystem.subhide {`
`display: none;`
`}`

`.subsystem {`
`display: anything;`
}

It should work

Comment: I disagree with this, the default is `display: block` for divs as defined by the spec. you should not be adding redundant code. also there is no need to add to the specificity of the class `.subhide` is enough.

Comment: "display: anything;" is not a valid CSS. There's no option "anything" for the property "display". Just FYI ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why, but this snippet works:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
 jQuery('#subs1')
  .click(function(){
  jQuery('body').find('.subsystem').addClass('subhide')})
});
```